# Print an inverse Z pattern

Tags: c

How to print an inverse Z pattern?

Code for a normal Z pattern:

```
int main() {
int n;

printf("Enter number of rows: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < n; column++) {
        if (row == 0 || row == n - 1 || column == n - 1 - row) {
            printf("* ");
        }
        else {
            printf("  ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

Output for the code above for n = 5:

```
* * * * *
      * 
    *  
  *
* * * * *
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: inverse in which direction? Upside down or left to right?

Comment: What is the problem? If you managed to write this one, I am sure you are capable of writing the other.

Comment: @Pablo These are the same :)

Comment: In line10 you should focus on the condition `column == n - 1 - row` and adapt it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. oh yeah, right.

Comment: ...although it won't be line 10 once you `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int column = n-1; column >=0; column--) {
            if (row == 0 || row == n - 1 || column == n - 1 - row) 
            {
                printf("* ");
            }
            else {
                printf("  ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward Z:

1. Row 0 = `* * * * * * * *`
2. Row 1 = N-2 blanks, 1 `*`
3. Row 2 = N-3 blanks, 1 `*`
4. Row 3 = N-4 blanks, 1 `*`
   …
5. Row N-4 = 3 blanks, 1 `*`
6. Row N-3 = 2 blanks, 1 `*`
7. Row N-2 = 1 blank, 1 `*`
8. Row N-1 = `* * * * * * * *`

Inverse Z:

1. Row 0 = `* * * * * * * *`
2. Row 1 = 1 blank, 1 `*`
3. Row 2 = 2 blanks, 1 `*`
4. Row 3 = 3 blanks, 1 `*`
   …
5. Row N-4 = N-4 blanks, 1 `*`
6. Row N-3 = N-3 blanks, 1 `*`
7. Row N-2 = N-2 blanks, 1 `*`
8. Row N-1 = `* * * * * * * *`

Tip: if you separate the `* * * * * *` output from the single `*` output, it should be easier to adjust the resulting code to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something i made for a Z pattern, to inverse, just replace the "x+1" at the end of the if statement

```
x = int(input("Enter size: "))

for i in range(0, x): #row
   for j in range(0, x): #columns
         if (i == 0 or i == x-1) or i+j==x-1:  #determines whether to print "X" or ""
               print("X", end="")
         else:
               print(" ", end="")
   print()
```